# How to scrape a page without pagination with requests and beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm scraping a web (using Python requests and beautifulsoup) and I need to go through all the pages of a list of items, but I need to click for next page and the code return just the 50th first rows in my code until now

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/se/public/view/b/licenciamento'
antenas = requests.get(url)

if antenas.status_code == 200:
print('Requisição bem sucedida!')
content = antenas.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find_all(name='table')

table_str = str(table)
df = pd.read_html(table_str)[0]
```

My goal is to scrape from all link automatically the entire table!

Comment: ‘To scrap’ means to throw away, to discard. You should use ‘scrape’

Answer (score 0):

This page uses a separate AJAX request to `http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/se/public/view/b/lic_table.php` to fetch tables, as you can see with the browser debugging tools (F12 -> Network). For pagination, a number seems to be passed with the `skip` form parameter.

Try getting each page separately, something like this:

```
url = 'http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/se/public/view/b/lic_table.php'

result_dfs = []

i = 0
while True:
  data = {
    'skip': i*50,
    'rpp': 50,
    'wfid': 'licencas'
  }
  r = requests.post(url, data=data)

  # process the results here...
  # df = ...

  # break when there are no more results
  if len(df.index) == 0:
    break

  result_dfs.append(df)

  i += 1

# put them all together
df = pd.concat(result_dfs)
```

There are a few other form parameters, not sure if those are needed.